# Dataflow Job Fails stating, java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: BundleFinalizer unsupported by non-portable Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are running a simple Data Flow Job that reads data from a Spanner DB and just displays the Changed Record's Mod Type. When we deploy the Job in Dataflow it always fails stating, the below error,

> Error message from worker: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: BundleFinalizer unsupported by non-portable Dataflow.\n        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SplittableProcessFnFactory$SplittableDoFnRunnerFactory.lambda$createRunner$2(SplittableProcessFnFactory.java:172)\n        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.OutputAndTimeBoundedSplittableProcessElementInvoker$1.bundleFinalizer(OutputAndTimeBoundedSplittableProcessElementInvoker.java:206)\n        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.changestreams.dofn.ReadChangeStreamPartitionDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)\n        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.OutputAndTimeBoundedSplittableProcessElementInvoker.invokeProcessElement(OutputAndTimeBoundedSplittableProcessElementInvoker.java:125)\n        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SplittableParDoViaKeyedWorkItems$ProcessFn.processElement(SplittableParDoViaKeyedWorkItems.java:567)

Below is the source code,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PipelineOptions pipelineOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create();
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(pipelineOptions);
        SpannerConfig spannerConfig = SpannerConfig.create().withProjectId("prj-test-1234")
                .withInstanceId("dbinstance1").withDatabaseId("dbtestnew");

        PCollection<String> changeRecord = pipeline
                .apply(SpannerIO.readChangeStream().withSpannerConfig(spannerConfig)
                        .withChangeStreamName("dbteststream").withMetadataDatabase("testmetadata"))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<DataChangeRecord, String>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void process(ProcessContext context) {
                        System.out.println("context " + context.element().getModType());
                       context.output(context.element().getModType().name());
                    }

                }));

        pipeline.run();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the `SpannerIO.readChangeStream()` transform which uses a feature (bundle finalization) that is only supported by Dataflow Runner v2. Please add following pipeline option to make your pipeline run using Dataflow Runner v2.

```
--experiments=use_runner_v2
```

Please see [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-runner-v2) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the documentation link!! Adding this option solved the problem!!